# how to include the Skype Kit java APIs inside an android application on Ecclipse IDE?

Tags: android

I am working on an application where I need to integrate the Skype Java APIs inside an android application.

Could some one provide any pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: Question is unclear - do you want to know about adding a jar file to the project or something else?

Comment: @Shade: I am trying to use the Skype Apis for an application , but not sure how to access the Skype Runtime inside ecclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the library (the .jar file) into the Build Path of the project and to put the libraries in the project folder. [This article](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29) could be quite useful.

Comment: Thanks. I am familiar with adding external libraries to your ecclipse application,however i am not having the skype jar with me. Does anyone have that?Currently i have the src files in Java that I am trying to add inside the source path of my app.

Comment: @MadScientist, I will vote down your question then, as it is unclear. See this page for info about SkypeKit: http://blogs.skype.com/developer/2010/06/skypekit_beta.html  However, the page says that SkypeKit is still in Beta and is currently invite only.

Answer (score 1):

SkypeKit is not a pure Java implementation. As I understand it is natively distributed for various processor architectures on linux (as well as windows and osx) It requires you to link to native libraries via JNI. That requires you to first download the Android NDK - http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html Beyond that bit of information I can not help as I do not have access to SkypeKit myself.