# Integrating Skype runtime in existing Android application

Tags: android, skype, skype4java

The binary distribution of the `Skypekit` SDK(beta) ships with binary Runtimes for different machine architectures(linux/win/mac-x86/arm-eabi). Usually, for integrating and leveraging Skype functionalities what we do is -

1. Start Runtime
2. Connect to it over TCP and
3. then pass command-protocol messages(For IM, Audio/Video chat).

**Per Skype FAQ:**
Although there are no public builds available for Android there is a Runtime for ARM architecture and there are Java Wrappers available for communicating with this Runtime.

**Question:**

1. Has anyone tried integrating Skype runtime in an existing Android application?
2. How can we setup and start the Skype Runtime from command line? I assume once this is figured out I can use Runtime API to invoke the same from my application?
3. Can we just package all the armeabi files and load them when the app initializes, initialize the runtime and maybe then connect to it on the said port and pass command protocol messages?

Any pointers on how this could be done?

Thanks.

Comment: I was able to start the Runtime from adb shell..need to figure out a way to connect to it..

Comment: Does the Skype Android SDK support allowing the SDP portion of the message to be modified, such that the media RTP streams will be routed to a different IP address and port than what the application is running on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any one looking for an answer, this was answered in another thread, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583487/hosting-an-executable-within-android-application).

Comment: Does the Skype4b Android SDK support allowing the SDP portion of the message to be modified, such that the media RTP streams will be routed to a different IP address and port than what the application is running on?

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking at this thread to see if it answers your questions already:

[how to include the Skype Kit java APIs inside an android application on Ecclipse IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195773/how-to-include-the-skype-kit-java-apis-inside-an-android-application-on-ecclipse)

Comment: I have seen it; the information is outdated. THe problem with Skypekit is that it is closed beta so not much is out there. I will continue my experiment this weekend. Hopefully, I will find something and post a note. Thanks for the suggestion, though!.. cheers!